# How do I pass the file directory and name of file to the PNG class to validate that the file is indeed a png

Tags: java

This is main where I select the file from a JFileDialog. I want to pass the filename and directory to the PNG class to check whether the file is a png or not. But I am stuck again help.

```
package file;    

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;

import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Driver {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{


        Files png = new PNG();//create an object of the class png in the parent class Files
        PNG Png = new PNG();//create an object of teh PNg class

        FileDialog FileWindow = new FileDialog(new Frame());//File dialog widnow
        FileWindow.setVisible(true);

        if (FileWindow.getFile() != null) {

            File FileDirectory = new File(FileWindow.getDirectory());//store the directory cheosen by user
            String[] Directory = FileDirectory.list();//creates an array of the directory

            for (int i = 0; i < Directory.length; i++) {

                if (Directory[i] != null) {
                    //Loops through the directory to find the file that match the file that the user selected           
                    if (Directory[i].matches(FileWindow.getFile()) || Directory[i].startsWith(FileWindow.getFile())) {


                        //if file is found it is stored in FileExtract           String FileExtract = Directory[i];

                        //This section gets the file extension

                        int dot = FileExtract.lastIndexOf(".");
                        String FileName = FileExtract.substring(0, dot);
                        String FileExtension = FileExtract.toUpperCase().substring(dot + 1);

                        //get the size of the file
                        File FileSize = new File(FileWindow.getDirectory(), FileExtract); 
                        //name and directory of file is passed to the PNG class to be validated
                        Png.isPng(FileDirectory, Directory[i]);                   

                        //prints out the information for that file
                        png.setFileName(FileName);
                        png.setFileType(FileExtension);
                        png.setFileSize(FileSize.length());

                        png.Display();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the PNG class I want to pass teh file name and directory here to confirm that the  file selected in the Jfilechooser is indeed a png file using the magic numbers.

```
package file;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class PNG extends Files {
    //Magic number or hex value for png file
    private static final int MAGIC[] = new int[] { 0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a }; 
    // name of teh file and directory is passed here             
    public void isPng(File dir, String file) throws Exception { 
        String[] listOfFiles = dir.list(); //Store the directory here
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
        {

            if (listOfFiles[i] != null) 
            {//Search foor the file the user chose in the drive class
                if(listOfFiles[i].matches(file) || listOfFiles[i].startsWith(file)){

                    //if teh file is found then it orints its name
                    System.out.print(file + "\n");

                    //but what i really want is to open that file an read its magic numbers or hex value to get its extension type.
                    //the commented out area is wat i cant figure and i think the FileInputStream is causing teh problem           
                    /* FileInputStream ins = new FileInputStream(file); 


             try { 
               for(int d = 0; d < MAGIC.length; ++d) { 
                  if(ins.read() != MAGIC[d]) { 
                System.out.print("File is not Png");
                  } 
                  else
                System.out.print("File is Png");
               } 

            } 
            finally { 
              ins.close(); 
            } */
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: any help or ideas anyone? Please??

Comment: Please can anyone come up wit any idea I jus edited the work hoping that would help

Comment: You don't say what the problem is. I also don't understand why you're looping through anything, I thought the user selected the file.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes the user selected the file in main in the Driver class but If I do not loop in the PNG class to find the file that was passed from the Driver class which the user selected then i wont be able to read the file. what I really want in teh PNG class is to read the File that was passed from teh Driver class so i can use the magic number to verify the file type

Comment: @sue yin, the idea is there but the execution is not so good. Why does PNG class have to traverse everything from files to directories? Why don't you make it a little bit atomic like this PNG just check a file. Let the other top class handle the loop through directories and files where if it is a file, then it will call PNG class to validate it?

Comment: @eee yes That is exactly what i want but i do not know hw to get it. Can u help me

Comment: Hmm I will help you by giving you a link to similar problem in a different way [http://www.java-forums.org/java-awt/9285-png-file-format-decoder-java.html](http://www.java-forums.org/java-awt/9285-png-file-format-decoder-java.html)

Comment: @eee oh boy, I jus  want to read the file so i can check its magic numbers. I dont understand where they read the file in that link

Comment: What is missing is to get a list of files and directories after opening a FileDialog or JFileChooser...but this is quite easy and it can be found on SO and Internet. After that, you can process the list for files only and validate them for PNG... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019478/how-to-get-directory-path-using-jfilechooser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019478/how-to-get-directory-path-using-jfilechooser)

Comment: @eee but haven't i done that already..I really dont can u jus tell me where it should go plz and i am using jfiledialog and not jfilechooser

Comment: @sue There is no difference between using JFileDialog or JFileChooser, both basically will get the same thing with the correct method; in this case, getting the currently selected directory. With the currently selected directory, you can use File.list() to get items of the current directory and individually check for a file type [http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.io/Filelist.htm](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.io/Filelist.htm)

Comment: @eee I dont mean to sound dumb or irritate u..but i did that in the PNG class..where I search through the directory and found the file without using the filechooser or the filedialog...But i jus cant read teh file

Comment: You should know that using `File.list()` not only lists down file names but also directory names. That is why after getting the list, you need to check for a file type, not a directory type using `File.isDirectory()` check first. When it is confirmed a file type, then you can further process it to check for magic number using a new `File` constructor

Comment: @eee can u write it so i can see wat u r saying..cus rite now  my brain is fried! please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this easy for your self, you should try to separate your code into different parts. The problem you are struggling with right now has really nothing to do with displaying file/folder selection dialogs nor with traversing folders.

I've chosen to create a method that checks whether one single file objects represents a PNG file using the [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number).

```
private final byte[] magic = { -119, 80, 78, 71 };

public boolean isPng(File file) throws IOException
{
    BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
    input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    boolean result = Arrays.equals(buffer, magic);
    input.close();
    return result;
}
```

This will help you clean up your code. Focus on trying to get shorter methods that only does *one* thing.

Also consider using beginning lower case letters for local variables and fields such as `fileDirectory` rather than `FileDirectory`, this will make your code easier to read for yourself and also other java programmers.

Comment: so if i put this in my code program it should run right? but if i only get the name of the file like u did there will it find the file whereever it is?

Comment: The `File` class in java does not represent a filename, it represents a file. Ok? You can create a `File` object representing any file in your filesystem. E.g. `new File("C:\\folder\\file.png")`

Comment: but I still dont kno hw to get it to work...could u implement that for me... cus i want the file selected in the Driver class to be sent to the PNG class for validation...and sent back to the Driver class if it is true so i can print the info for taht file

Comment: if you look closely at *your own* code you actually create a `File` instance representing the file your intrested in - It's called `FileSize`. I recommend a rename to `file`. Just pass this instance to the `isPng` method above.

Comment: I tried that but it only show the file size and its type and not showing the name of the file...also when i do this: if(Png.isPng(file){   png.setFileName(FileName);
                           png.setFileType(fileExtension);
                           png.setFileSize(file.length());
                           png.Display();
                        } it comes up blank

Comment: oh I had an error that is why...on other thing...is magic = { -119, 80, 78, 71 }; the conversion for MAGIC ={0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47}; respectively??

Comment: yeah, it's the magic numbers for a PNG file. I took it from here http://www.garykessler.net/library/magic.html. In java we only have signed bytes, thats why the numbers are a bit weird... The three last bytes are the ascii characters "PNG".

Comment: I dont c these values : -119, 80, 78, 71 for the png oh and what is the -119

Comment: Rather look at the official specification: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.1/PNG-Rationale.html#R.PNG-file-signature